Have the Ruby logger create log files only if log messages exists
I want Ruby to log into a file, but only if there are acutally log messages. I don't want to get empty log files without any messages.
I used the answer at Can I disable the log header for ruby logger? to keep Ruby from adding a header to the log file, but it is still being created, now without any content if there are no messages. How can I make Ruby to create the log file only if there are messages to log?

Why not just delete the log using #at_exit or whatever when it contains nothing but the header? That seems low-effort. Otherwise, what problem are you really solving for, and why do you care if the logger creates a log file but doesn't use it?

It would be extremely inefficient when a logger always had to check if the log files exist before being able to write.

@ToddA.Jacobs: I have mutliple apps that only log on errors and that are executed from other apps, so it is not so easy and not very clean to use an "at_exit" to undo work that should have been done in the first place.

@spickermann: This would only be a simple nil check: "if dev.nil? then dev = create file" or the like. No cost at all.

You're starting from a false premise. Why are all your apps writing to entirely separate log files? If that's a problem, use syslog, remote syslog, or similar. Your log entries should be the differentiator between related apps, not necessarily separate log files. This is a self-inflicted X/Y problem, but if it really bothers you then you'll have to search for or build a logging solution that makes you happier.

Would it be a problem to use the log4r-gem?
https://rubygems.org/gems/log4r

@Jomo Are you developing in a Rails application? Plain Ruby scripts shouldn't be creating logfiles without explicitly being told to do so.
